# Making server redirect to another folder with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Can i make a htaccess file that redirect from the root of my project to another folder.
So if i usually write 192.168.1.39/public to get to my library where i store the files that i want the users to see.
I would like to only write 192.168.1.39 instead.

Can you do that with a .htaccess file?

Comment: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Transparently_redirect_your_root_directory_to_a_subdirectory - You can also set the home www folder in your webserver's configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In the htaccess file in root, add  this rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^$ /folder [NC,L]
```

^$ matches the hompage and rewrites it to the folder.